# Ошибка сборки после обновления Android studio

Tags: android

Возникают ошибки при изменени Gradle на 26.0.2

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Вот сам Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "тут типо название"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 4
    versionName "4.5.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Comment: Саму суть ошибки-то не указали. И 26.0.2 это не версия Gradle.

Comment: У вас все support библиотеки каких попало версий. укажите для всех одну и ту же версию для начала, студия сама предложит какие версии актуальные 27.0.0

Comment: великие люди спасибо решено вауля

Answer (score 24):

Суть ошибки AAPT2 в том что теперь Android Studio ищет ресурсы ".gradle" в пути "С://User//пользователь//.gradle".
И если у вас имя пользователя прописано русским алфавитом - то каюк.:) это текстирование изменения.
(хотя до обновления это прокатывало))).

Исправляется следующим образом в настройках:
-> Settings -> Build, Execution -> Gradle ->
Изменить строчку "Service directory path" на "C:/Users/Public/.gradle"

После этого сделать ребилд проекта и - вуаля! все работает.
И с новыми проектами уже проблем не будет.

Comment: спасибо, спас, мало того что сдк глючит при полльзователе на русском, так еще и градл))

Comment: да, прям вообще огонь ответ) помог

Answer (score 3):

Привет! Да, проблема в том что, имя юзера компа на русском языке.
У меня давно такая же проблема возникала на предыдущей версии Android Studio. Выход нашел не самый лучший, но рабочий: на компе создал новую учетную запись на латыни, установил Android Studio и все стало работать.

Но тут есть минусы: первое время приходилось постоянно переключаться, т.к. какие-то данные остались у русскоязычного пользователя - фотки, Photoshop, ссылки какие-то, да и вообще вся жизнь у русскоязычного пользователя. И если у тебя старый проект, то сложно будет туда все перенести.

Думал перевести все данные и программы на англоязычного, но есть много рабочих программ, которые нужно переустанавливать, а это очень муторно.
 Пока на 2 логина работаю.

Answer (score 0):

Решение простое, добавить следующую строку в файлы gradle.properties `android.enableAapt2=false`

Comment: Я бы не назвал это решением.

Comment: Это "костыль". После удаления aapt1 оно опять поломается