# Ошибка при Sync Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Здравствуйте! После обновления Android Studio до версии 3.0.1 и версии gradle до 4.1 стала возникать ошибка при попытке синхронизировать gradle, добавляю скрин:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы выяснить что это за ошибка и возможные методы ее устранения. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/736358/11515

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка связана с тем, что студия ищет ресурсы ".gradle" в пути "C://User//Пользователь//.gradle" и имя пользователя у вас на русском языке.Нужно либо создавать новую учетную запись на латыни и устанавливать в нее студию,либо добавить строку "android.enableAapt2=false" в  gradle.properties.