# android studio создаёт поломанный проект

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Создаю проект и выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1857: error: resource layout/abc_select_dialog_material (aka com.example.myapplication:layout/abc_select_dialog_material) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1865: error: resource anim/abc_popup_enter (aka com.example.myapplication:anim/abc_popup_enter) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1866: error: resource anim/abc_popup_exit (aka com.example.myapplication:anim/abc_popup_exit) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1869: error: resource anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom (aka com.example.myapplication:anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1870: error: resource anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom (aka com.example.myapplication:anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2033: error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_text_material (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_btn_colored_text_material) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2087: error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2118: error: resource color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2121: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_primary_text_material_dark) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2122: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_light (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_primary_text_material_light) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2123: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2124: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2125: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2126: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2127: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2128: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2129: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2154: error: resource color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2157: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_light (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_primary_text_material_light) not found.
D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2158: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.myapplication:color/abc_primary_text_material_dark) not found.

Command: C:\Users\Алексей\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d99a2b4961e34e4185fdd2cb1ea64091\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        D:\Sdk_Manager\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        D:\MyApplication2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.myapplication\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        D:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Что это может быть?

Comment: обычно идея просит сама что-то докачать. попробуйте куда-нибудь нажать, чтобы началось скачивание файлов

Comment: или как вариант, скачайте готовый проект и запустите

Comment: может чем-то поможет в вашей ситуации - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0

Comment: Возможная причина и решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736532/11515

Answer (score 0):

Обнови студию заново со всеми новыми компонентами

Comment: Обновлял, все так же

Comment: обязательно все зависимости SDK