# Проблемы с gradle при компиляции нового проекта (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени суток.
Поставил Android Studio, создал проект, а при запуске выдает ошибку (скриншот ниже).
Пробовал удалять папку gradle и делать rebuild, не помогло.
В gradle минимальная версия СДК 25, проект тоже на этой версии. 
Видел в интернете, как ребята писали что нужно в файле манифеста выставить минимальную версию сдк тоже, но у себя не нашел такой строки, как у них на скринах (Видимо в новой версии андроид студио упразднили данную функцию).
Windows 7 у меня, если это поможет как-то.

[image: Скриншот с ошибкой]

Вот начало лога с ошибками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уверен решение простое, но я совсем зеленый, поэтому прошу помощи.

Comment: Не упразднили, вручную добавить можно. Но в данном случае это не поможет.

Comment: Понял. А что тогда поможет?

Comment: @Dmytto, вам лучше выложить весь лог ошибки. По скриншоту не понятно в каком месте и какая ошибка и gradle мне кажется тут не причем

Comment: Может быть, вы что-нибудь полезное найдете тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736358/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-android-studio